# How to stop Vim from automatically inserting the comment leader when Enter is pressed?

Tags: vim

If I'm typing a comment in gVim like this

`// this is a comment`

and I hit ENTER, it will automatically start the next line with //, so it looks like this:

```
// this is a comment
//
```

But usually I don't want to write more comments when using this commenting style. Can I stop gVim from automatically doing this, while still keeping the auto-completing of the /* .. */ commenting style?

Comment: This [wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Disable_automatic_comment_insertion) talks about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer from mine since you don't want to have this triggered for `/*` … `*/` comments.

Use:

```
inoremap <expr> <enter> getline('.') =~ '^\s*//' ? '<enter><esc>S' : '<enter>'
```

For `o` and `O`:

```
nnoremap <expr> O getline('.') =~ '^\s*//' ? 'O<esc>S' : 'O'
nnoremap <expr> o getline('.') =~ '^\s*//' ? 'o<esc>S' : 'o'
```

Comment: maybe `imap` instead of `inoremap` will preserve some behaviour of S.

Comment: That's perfect! Can you make this work for hitting O on a comment line as well?

Answer (score 35):

To disable it while hitting ENTER in insert mode, do `:set formatoptions-=r`

To disable it while hitting o or O in normal mode, do `:set formatoptions-=o`

See `:help 'formatoptions'` and `:help fo-table`.

Alternatively, you can still press <kbd>CTRL-U</kbd> in insert mode if you want to delete characters from start of line till the cursor.

Comment: Thanks, but this also disables the auto-completing on hitting ENTER after making a `/*` -style comment. I'd like to keep that option, but disable similar behaviour on hitting ENTER after making a `//` -style comment. Is this possible?

Comment: I like this solution. I have the following line in my .vim.rc:
`autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * set formatoptions-=o`
So by default, I can still use carriage return to create multi-line comments.  When I'm done commenting, I type 'o'.

Comment: Sadly, this is not working for me in RHEL.  Whoever thought this was a good idea to turn on by default should have their credentials removed.

Answer (score 3):

To **permanently** disable this behavior, add `autocmd FileType * set formatoptions-=r` in your `.vimrc`/`init.vim`.

Comment: That seems to be @Benoit's top answer with an extra step, no?

Comment: @DominikStańczak Benoit's answer only works for the current session, mine works **permanently**.

Comment: Not if you add `set formatoptions...` to `vimrc`, which you could, AFAIK?

Comment: @DominikStańczak Adding `set formatoptions-=r` to the config file won't work.

Answer (score 2):

To have it disabled every time you use vim, open your .vimrc file and add the following line:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * setlocal formatoptions-=r
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding:

```
set fo-=ro
```

in `~/.vimrc` was sufficient,

to disable **R**eturn and **o**/O keys in normal mode from autocommenting.

`fo` is a shorthand for `formatoptions`, and `-=` is to subtract certain keys while retaining the rest of the original value.

The value of `fo` can be shown using `set fo?` in command (`ex`) mode.

Issue `help fo` to read more about option in the vim's internal manual pages.