# How to disable the auto comment in shell script vi editing?

Tags: shell, vi, comments

I'm using vi(m) to edit a shell script and when I insert a comment and type , the new line came with a comment already.
How can I disable it ?

Ex :
   # When I type enter, the comment simbol # below is inserted automaticaly.
   #

Answer (score 67):

I was finding the same answer, try

```
:set paste
```

this may help

Comment: It would be quicker to manually delete the extra comment character than to type that each time to toggle paste mode.

Comment: Super helpful, especially in the case of pasting a large chunk of text that has a single comment already set, thus commenting everything else.

Comment: `vi ~/.vimrc` and add the line `set paste` without a colon

Answer (score 14):

I found some links solving your issue:

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/vim-auto-comment-696916/

  > You're probably looking for this command
  >
  > `:set paste`
  >
  > Or you can add this line to your ~/.vimrc (which will allow you to toggle between paste and nopaste with Ctrl+P)
  >
  > `nm <C-P> :se invpaste paste?<CR>`
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=833353

  > to resolve problem with inserting some text/code in vim with comments you can just add in your .vimrc file this line:
  >
  > `set pastetoggle=`
  >
  > that will make `set paste` on pasting and `set nopaste` when it's done..
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_automatic_comment_insertion

  > To disable it just once for the current session:
  >
  > `:set formatoptions-=cro`
  >
  > To disable for all files and sessions, use this:
  >
  > `autocmd FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o`
  >
  > This sets up an auto command that fires after any filetype-specific plugin; the command removes the three flags from the 'formatoptions' option that control the automatic insertion of comments. With this in your vimrc, a comment character will not be automatically inserted in the next line under any situation.
  >
  > Use this command to check your format options:
  >
  > `:set formatoptions?`

Hope it's useful, let me know if you got it clear.
Bye

Answer (score 1):

This feature is useful, how about just pressing `Ctrl-u` in insert mode?
it will delete everything until the beginning of the line. By doing that you do not lose auto comments.

See more [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/how-can-i-get-vim-to-stop-putting-comments-in-front-of-new-lines) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896003/how-do-i-stop-vim-from-auto-creating-comments-on-enter-press):

Answer (score 1):

The vi stack exchange documents another excellent option:

https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/1985/12256

You can add something like below to your `.vimrc` file to ensure shell scripts won't automatically insert the comment leader.

```
au FileType sh setlocal fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o
```

The vim documentation will tell you what each of the options (c, r, o) mean.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the option:

```
:see paste
```

I have gone through many blogs where there was an option:

```
:see formatoptions-=cro
```

Which did not work!

Comment: can you edit this one? i'm permanently getting "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later."   :see shoult be :set ofcourse

Comment: You should always run `:verbose set <option>` to see where and option was last set. It's an almost guarantee the FileType plugin is overriding your setting and you should use one the examples above and below to set it instead. `r` inserts comments on newlines. `c` wraps with comment if an only if you have `t` and **textwidth** is set. See `:h fo-table`